# Python - How to Access Data via a Simple Hierarchical Class Dependency

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I'm encapsulating some data in a `Data` class, which loads all data into memory and provides it to other classes. These are managed by a `Wrapper` class. Thereby, I wonder if I can change the data, as seen by all other classes, by just changing the `Wrapper` class instance `wrp`? Here is a minimal toy example illustrating what I want to achieve:

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.d = x

class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self,_data):
        self.data = _data
        self.intl = Internal(self.data)        

class Internal(object):    
    def __init__(self,_data):
        self.data = _data

data = Data([5])
wrp = Wrapper(data)
print(wrp.data.d)       #[5]
print(wrp.intl.data.d)  #[5]

data = Data([6])        # new data instance
wrp.data = data         # but still same old wrapper instance 
print(wrp.data.d)       #[6]
print(wrp.intl.data.d)  #[5]  <- want [6] here
```

**EDIT**

To achieve what I want, I could do:

```
data          = Data([5])
wrp           = Wrapper(data)
data2         = Data([6])
wrp.data      = data2
wrp.intl.data = data2
```

I would like to change the classes above in a way, that allows me to set the data  attribute for all existing class instances in just one line like the following:

```
wrp.data      = data2
```

Now, `wrp.intl` holds an instance of the `Internal` class. This instance has itself a `wrp.int.data` attribute which should now point to `data2` as well.

In the real code, the `Data` class instance will load a lot of data into memory and also provides some methods all along. It's instance is passed to the objects (instances of other classes like `Internal`) contained in the `Wrapper` instance (here `wrp`). That works fine. However, at some point I may need to update the data by creating a new `Data` instance (here `data2`) which then has to be swapped for the old one in every object within `wrp`.

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.d = x

class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self,_data):
        self.data = _data
        self.intl = Internal(_data)        

class Internal(object):    
    def __init__(self,_data):
        self.data = _data

data = Data([5])
wrp = Wrapper(data)
print(wrp.data.d)       #[5]
print(wrp.intl.data.d)  #[5]

data = Data([6])        # new data instance
wrp.data = data         # but still same old wrapper instance
```

> ```
> wrp.intl = Internal(data)
> ```

```
print(wrp.data.d)       #[6]
print(wrp.intl.data.d)  #[5]  <- want [6] here
```

gives:

```
[5]
[5]
[6]
[6]
```

What I wonder about is how do you expect something to change if you haven't changed it?

Another variant giving what you want to achieve:

```
data = Data([6])        # new data instance
wrp = Wrapper(data)     # but still same old wrapper instance 
print(wrp.data.d)       #[6]
print(wrp.intl.data.d)  #[5]  <- want [6] here
```

**All the above is already a correct answer and gives you what you want to achieve, but ... I suppose you will probably have it THIS WAY**:

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.d = x
```

> ```
> class Wrapper(object):
>     def __init__(self,_data):
>         self._data = data
>         self.intl = Internal(_data)        
>     def _get_data(self):
>         return self._data
>     def _set_data(self, value):
>         self._data = value
>         self.intl = Internal(value)
>     data = property(_get_data, _set_data)
> ```

```
class Internal(object):    
    def __init__(self,_data):
        self.data = _data

data = Data([5])
wrp = Wrapper(data)
print(wrp.data.d)       #[5]
print(wrp.intl.data.d)  #[5]

data = Data([6])        # new data instance
wrp.data = data         # but still same old wrapper instance 
print(wrp.data.d)       #[6]
print(wrp.intl.data.d)  #[5]  <- want [6] here
```

this also gives:

```
[5]
[5]
[6]
[6]
```

Comment: Thank you, here you create a new instance of `Internal`. I was hoping to even keep the old one. So in a way, I just want to pass a reference of the `Data` instance to the constructor of the `Wrapper` instance which I can "swap" anytime for everyone "using" it. Maybe, it's just not possible this way.

Comment: @Tim Have you been through my ENTIRE answer? Which part of my answer do you refer to with your comment? And WHAT is what you want to achieve if none of the provided variants suits your needs? Or in other words, WHY is none of the three provided variants a solution? And WHAT does you consider as not possible?

Comment: P.S. all of the three provided variants achieve what you want according to the request: `print(wrp.intl.data.d)  #[5]  <- want [6] here`

Comment: Sry, I wasn't precise enough in my question. Regarding my example, I'm looking for a way to change the data attribute of the `Wrapper` class instance (`wrp.data`) which willl be passed on, so the `Internal` class instance which was created in the constructor of the `Wrapper` class should be preserved while it's own data attribute (`wrp.intl.data`) should be changed. I'll edit my question later today. Sry, I'm doing this for a lil home project. I'm not a professional.

Comment: @Tim When you edit your question try to be as precise as possible about what the outcome is and what you expect it to be considered ALL of what was created/changed. From what you write in your comment I understand that you want to change the value of a class attribute, but so that it doesn't change (it should be [6], but it should be [5] to preserve what it was before) - this is a logical contradiction in itself and therefore not possible ... I am curious how it turn out to be, i.e. if you are not clear in what you want or I am wrong supposing here a logical contradiction.